# How to make svg line get bolder when its click

Tags: javascript, svg

I have group of polygon consists of other polygon inside. I want to make the polygon line get bolder when its click. Is it posible? how can I make it?

here's my code

```
<div id="svgselect" style="width: 610px; height: 230px;">
      <!-- background-color:red -->
      <svg version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%">
        <g transform="scale(1.5)" id="gmain">

          <g id="P17" transform="translate(25,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B17"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">17</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P16" transform="translate(50,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B16"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">16</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P15" transform="translate(75,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B15"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">15</text>

          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a class to a poly ex:

```
<polygon class="line" points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
```

then add this js code

```
$('.line').click(function () {
    $(this).attr("stroke-width", parseFloat($(this).attr("stroke-width"))+0.5 );
});
```

then they will increase every click

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qgxhgs44/

*note adding jquery is needed

Comment: that's work. how to make it bolder only with one click?

Comment: just change the stroke-width parameter.. see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3cuueor/

Answer (score 1):

Target your specific selector and change the stroke-width. I am going to giving you an example:

```
var select = document.querySelector('polygon');
select.addEventListener('click',function(){
  select.setAttribute("stroke-width", "3");
});
```

Comment: thank you, its get bolder but still in wrong position.

Comment: you can set  classes to the polygon and change its property for fixing the position